# Angular js powered website how can we trigger in android

Tags: javascript, android, angular

There is an angular website , I want to pre populate form text fields, I am writing javaScript script and executing it works but text field shows error. Example snippet. How to achieve this without error

```
document.getElementById('mat-input-0').value = 'qwerty@gmail.com'
```

I think validation errors but how to avoid this error

Comment: you should be using `[(ngModel)]= "yourValue"`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I am not sure about that 3 rt party site how they are receiving dat

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: ex:  there is an email field , Using the snippet i am setting the email value to the input box, but it shows error enter valid email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to **dispatch input event** after change:

```
const elem = document.getElementById('mat-input-0');
elem.value = 'qwerty@gmail.com';
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Comment: I am able to see the form without error , But on clicking submit it shows some error

Comment: What kind of error? Is it related to input field in question? It seems to be working for me, would you be able to share stackblitz?

Comment: https://new.camsonline.com/Investors/Statements/Consolidated-Account-Statement

Can you check this form i want to prefilll but getting error

Comment: const elem = document.getElementById('mat-input-0');
elem.value = 'qwerty@gmail.com';
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

Comment: @Rameshsambu each page is wired differently, looking at page in question, it seems to be making XHR call after change event. Use: `const elem = document.getElementById('mat-input-0'); elem.value = 'test@gmail.com';
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));`
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

Comment: It helped me.It saved my time

Comment: is it possible to find the Div changes in the site. I tried to submit the data after that need to close the screen